# Website redirect when switching host

Tags: html, .htaccess, hosting

I have created a website for someone and while their new hosting was been set up I added a website redirect to my site.

Now that their hosting is set up I removed the redirect and strange things are happening depending on how you go to their site

If you go to www.example.com it redirects still
If you go to http://example.com it doesn't redirect

I've check everything including the .htaccess file can anyone help?

Comment: Have you removed recently? It might take time for DNS records to change. (i.e. if you used dns redirects.)

Comment: I redirected using http not dns

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you could post your .htaccess here.

Comment: @user3516962 my .htacess file is bank

Comment: I think user3* meant the code you used to redirect before you removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not coding issue it is a hosting setting you are asked priority of the website link to be used as wwww.example.com or example.com
you can change it
below image is added how to change on godaddy

http://prntscr.com/8i869p